# Drag and Drop button into a panel in c#,net

Tags: c#, visual-studio, c#-4.0, drag-and-drop, drag

I need the code for the panel to hold the button. If the button is dragged and dropped into the panel. The panel should hold the button. In simple words, To drag and drop a button into a panel in run time. I didn't find the answer in the net. Please comment if you have any idea. Thanks in advance